# AssertJ - continue with fluent assertions after checking class

Tags: java, fluent, assertj

Say I have a `Map<String, Action>` and I go like this:

```
    assertThat( spyActionMap.get( "a" ) ).isInstanceOf( Action.class );
```

... passes.  Now I want to check that the `Action` obtained is the right one:

```
    assertThat( spyActionMap.get( "a" ) ).isInstanceOf( Action.class ).getValue( Action.NAME ).isEqualTo( "Go crazy" );
```

... doesn't compile, not surprisingly.  Is there any way to do this kind of thing?

Comment: Please provide some more context like the `Action` class or at least the relevant parts of it. Does it have a `getValue` method? What is `Action.NAME`?
What are you specifically trying to test?

Comment: You merely need to look up Javadoc to answer first & second questions.  The answer to your 3rd question is, I'm afraid: if you need to ask...

Comment: Telling me to look up Javadoc is hinting me that you could mean the interface `javax.swing.Action`, is that right? I see it has a static field `NAME` and even a method `getValue` .  It would be helpful if you provide that info in your question (at least with a tag) in the first place.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try [isInstanceOfSatisfying](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj/core-8/api/org/assertj/core/api/AbstractAssert.html#isInstanceOfSatisfying-java.lang.Class-java.util.function.Consumer-) and specify your assertions in a `Consumer`:

```
Object yoda = new Jedi("Yoda", "Green");
Object luke = new Jedi("Luke Skywalker", "Green");

Consumer<Jedi> jediRequirements = jedi -> {
   assertThat(jedi.getLightSaberColor()).isEqualTo("Green");
   assertThat(jedi.getName()).doesNotContain("Dark");
};

assertThat(yoda).isInstanceOfSatisfying(Jedi.class, jediRequirements);
assertThat(luke).isInstanceOfSatisfying(Jedi.class, jediRequirements);
```

Comment: Thanks... as one of the main people behind AssertJ, do you not think it might be nice if the `Assert` interface returned by `isInstanceOf` (and similar methods) could not somehow "swap" it with the instance checked by it cast to the class in question?  The solution you give illustrates the use of one more useful tool in the AssertJ toolbox... but it's perhaps not ideally "fluent" (obviously I have no idea how difficult it would be to engineer my idea...!)

Comment: Due to java limitations with generics, it is unfortunately not possible, this has been discussed in https://github.com/joel-costigliola/assertj-core/issues/683 which led to the `isInstanceOfSatisfying` solution.